# Page won't load trying to run this jquery/javascript code using $(document).ready(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Etch-a-sketch js: (jquery is also used in this code)

```
// Function for creating a grid, num is designate rows + columns

function createGrid(num) {
    for (var rows=0; rows < num; columns++) {
        for (var columns=0; columns < num; columns++) {
            $('#container').append("<div class='grid'></div");
        }        
    }

    $('.grid').width(960/num);
    $('.grid').height(960/num);
}

// Function to clear grid

function gridClear() {
     $('.grid').remove();
}

// Function to refresh grid and ask for new grid dimension

function refreshGrid() {
    var dime = prompt("Choose your new dimensions");
    gridClear();
    creatGrid(dime);
}
```

Below is code for creating a 16x16 grid when page loads, hover effect to change color of square and click of button to refresh Grid and ask for new dimensions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    createGrid(16);

    $('.grid').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','black');
    });

    $('.but').click (function () {
        refreshGrid();  
        $('.grid').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color','black');
        });    
    });
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question. Add some more description and clear your example code.

Comment: You need to edit your original post not as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

It's this part that is causing the issue:

```
for (var rows=0; rows < num; columns++)
```

Your loop never finishes as you are not incrementing `rows`.